Getting error Rust nightly not installed when starting an srtool container to build the runtime
I am starting a srtool container to build my runtime. I am using the following command
srtool build --root --package borderless-runtime --runtime-dir node/runtime  --build-opts="--features=fast-runtime"


and then i get the following
WARNING: You are using docker. We recommend using podman instead.
WARNING: You are using docker. We recommend using podman instead.
Found 1.77.0, we will be using docker.io/paritytech/srtool:1.77.0 for the build
 Substrate Runtime Toolbox - srtool v0.15.0 
              - by Chevdor -
info: override toolchain for '/build' set to '1.77.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
  Building borderless-runtime as release using rustc 1.77.0 (aedd173a2 2024-03-17)
⏳ That can take a little while, be patient... subsequent builds may be faster.
   Since you have to wait a little, you may want to learn more about Substrate runtimes:
   https://docs.substrate.io/learn/architecture/
warning: virtual workspace defaulting to `resolver = "1"` despite one or more workspace members being on edition 2021 which implies `resolver = "2"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: for more details see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#resolver-versions
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
    .
    .
    .
    .
error: failed to run custom build command for `borderless-runtime v4.0.0 (/build/node/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/build/node/runtime/target/srtool/release/build/borderless-runtime-14915b32115d2b35/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  Rust nightly not installed, please install it!

I think i have installed nightly.
Using rustup default gives me:
active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-10-09-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (overridden by '/home/rrr/borderless-node-rrr/rust-toolchain')
rustc 1.66.0-nightly (8796e7a9c 2022-10-08)


I also have a toolchain file for my node.
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2022-10-09"
components = [ "rustfmt", "clippy" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]

I am not able to understand why is this not working.

srtool will force use its built-in rustc version.
See:

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/issues/1223
https://github.com/paritytech/srtool/pull/68
https://github.com/chevdor/srtool-actions/pull/22

I assume your toolchain file locates at the root of your project. So, it won't work under the runtime folder.
My solution is soft-link the toolchian file to the runtime folder. Then it can override the srtool's default one.

This worked for me

Then please mark this as the answer, thanks.
